# Regex to match not full uppercase representation of a specific word

Tags: regex

There's a word, let's say `stackoverflow`. I would like to find EVERY instance of this word, where it's **NOT** written in **FULL UPPERCASE**.

So, example I'm looking for:

- StackOverflow
- STACKOVERFlow
- stackoverflow

... etc

But I don't want to include:

- STACKOVERFLOW
- stackexchange

Is it a problem which can be solved with pure regex? Regex engine is not specified, feel free to use whatever supports your feature needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that would work in other flavors as well e.g. `Javascript` or `python`:

```sh
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[sS][tT][aA][cC][kK][oO][vV][eE][rR][fF][lL][oO][wW]\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FOiOKg/1)

If you're using `PCRE` or Java then you can use:

```sh
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)(?i)stackoverflow(?-i)\b
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?![A-Z]+\b)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match of we have all upper case letter before matching a word boundary
- `(?i)`: Enable inline ignore case mode
- `stackoverflow`: Match `stackoverflow` in any case
- `(?-i)`: Disable inline ignore case mode
- `\b`: Word boundary

Answer (score 3):

You may try using the following pattern:

```regex
\b(?!STACKOVERFLOW\b)(?i)stackoverflow\b
```

### Demo

This pattern says to:

```
\b                   match a word boundary
(?!STACKOVERFLOW\b)  assert that the word is not STACKOVERFLOW in all caps
(?i)stackoverflow    then match "stackoverflow" with each letter in any case
\b                   closing word boundary
```

This answer assumes that your regex engine supports the `(?i)` case insensitive flag.

Another approach to your problem would be to simply do two separate matches, one for `STACKOVERFLOW` and the other a case insensitive search.